# How to get Windows driver for my device to open an html file when the device is connected to computer?

Tags: winapi, device-driver, java-web-start

I have a USB to serial port device and the associated device driver for Windows (written by someone at work). Is it possible to get the Windows driver for my device to open an html file when the device is connected to computer?

The html file would have a link that runs a Java Webstart application. So the html file would be written out onto disk by the driver when it was installed and whenever the device is plugged in and the driver invoked, it launches the application after the user clicks the link in the browser. This is the easy part.

The hard part is knowing how to get the driver to open the html file. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're interesting is manipulating a file, you can use the corresponding kernel APIs. See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565384(v=vs.85).aspx . Read carefully, there some things to watch out from that do not exist in user mode.

Comment: I want to write an html file to the disk, and then say `open('myfile.html')` whenever the device is plugged in and the driver detects it. Is your link sufficient? (I am clueless about Windows device drivers).

Comment: The link explains how to performs files manipulation. You also need to communicate with user space - and that a completely different story

Comment: I looked at the the links but wondered - how would the driver launch the browser and open the html file in it? (In a command window, simply typing myfile.html will open it in the browser).

Comment: It won't. That's what I've written in my previous comment. Driver needs to communicate with some user space component, which in turn, upon driver notification, will launch the browser